# How many books are there in "The Hitchhikers Guide To The Galaxy" series?

Tags: books, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

I have seen an edition of *The Hitchhikers Guide To The Galaxy* that was a compilation of four books, *The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy*, *The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*, *Life, the Universe and Everything*, and *So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish*.

The book described itself as *A trilogy in four parts*, but after I finished *Life, the Universe and Everything* and started *So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish*, it's quite clear that the original series is only a trilogy, and the fourth book is just an epilogue, of sorts.

When I searched for the series on the Kindle Store, there were compilations claiming to have five or six books in them. Ever since then, the question has bugged me: how many books are there, officially, in *The Hitchhiker's Guide to The Galaxy* series?

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to get your answer, but have you considered Googling?  After all, the first google result is a link to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), which clearly lists the [novels in the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Novels).

Comment: The 4-book compilation was obviously written before "Mostly Harmless" was written/released.

Comment: Simply not enough.

Comment: @motoDrizzt - Having read '[And Another Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Another_Thing..._(novel))' I'm sad to say, *one too many*.

Comment: The question should read: *How many books are there in "The Hitchhiker **Trilogy**"?*

Comment: *Life, the Universe and Everything* is actually pretty much a recycled Doctor Who plot that Adams was never able to bring to the screen. The original conception of the *Hitchhiker* plot only went through *Restaurant*. (*Hitchhiker* supposedly ends where it does because the draft was long overdue, so the publisher asked "how far are you?" to which Adams replied he was merely about halfway through; the publisher told him "finish the page you're on".)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

## The right answer of course is 42!

More seriously, but not too much, *[The Hitchhikers Guide To The Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)* is famous for being a *Trilogy in Five Parts* (this should be taken with the same ironic spirit of the books themselves of course!)

### The novels

The main novels of the series are five:

1. [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(novel)) (1979)
2. [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe) (1980)
3. [Life, the Universe and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life,_the_Universe_and_Everything) (1982)
4. [So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Long,_and_Thanks_for_All_the_Fish) (1984)
5. [Mostly Harmless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless) (1992)

A sixth book, not written by Douglas Adams but commissioned by his wife, was written by Eoin Colfer:

6. [And Another Thing...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_Another_Thing..._(novel)) (2008)

### The short story

There is also a short story, by Douglas Adams himself, set in the *Hitchhiker*'s universe:

- [Young Zaphod Plays It Safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Zaphod_Plays_It_Safe) (1986)

### The collection

To my knowledge, the most complete omnibus edition that collects all the aforementioned works by Douglas Adams (so, without *And Another Thing...*) is:

- [The Ultimate Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13.The_Ultimate_Hitchhiker_s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) (1997)

### And another thing...

It is worth noting that there is also a book called:

- [The Salmon of Doubt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Salmon_of_Doubt) (2002)

This is a collection of various writings by Douglas Adams, including an unfinished draft of a new novel, called itself *The Salmon of Doubt*; the original intention of the author was to make it an installment of his other *[Dirk Gently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently)* series, but later he thought that it would be better suited to be a part of the *Hitchhiker* series.

---

*A complete list of works and collections pertaining to this series is available at the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?165).*

Comment: You might want to add that a sixth book has been added to the series, *And another thing*, by Eoin Colfer. This has been requested by Adams himself before his death

Comment: It always disappointed me that it started being referred to as "A trilogy in five parts" once _Mostly Harmless_ was released. It would have been infinitely superior to call it a "trilogy in four parts" that had five books in it.

Comment: And part 5 advertised itself as "The book that gives a whole new meaning to the word 'trilogy'.

Comment: Mostly Harmless said on the cover (on at least one edition) "The fifth book in the increasingly inaccurately named Hitchhikers Trilogy".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would upvote your answer but you already have 42 votes!

Comment: Almost upvoted! Close one!

Comment: @David Richerby I definitely remember back in the day, at least in Germany, seeing ads for Mostly Harmless announcing it as (the german equivalent of) "Volume five of the four part trilogy", so you're definitely not the only one with that opinion

Comment: @armb: I recall the wording to be »The fifth book in the increasingly inaccurately named trilogy of four.«

Comment: @Joey -- no, armb's definitely right. 
 It was the UK first-edition hardcover that had (very nearly) the text he quoted: https://pictures.abebooks.com/isbn/9780517577400-uk-300.jpg

Comment: And the US first edition had the wording I quoted, because when I searched to confirm my memory of an approximate version, that was what turned up on Wikipedia :-)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless#/media/File:Mostly_Harmless_Harmony_front.jpg

Comment: I can verify that the Ultimate Edition includes all works **but** And Another Thing, that's the edition I have at home.

Comment: In German, "Mostly Harmless" is subtitled "Der fünfte Band einer vierbändigen Trilogie" (Volume 5 of a four-volumed trilogy).

Comment: This answer would be even better with a mention of The Salmon of Doubt

Comment: Re: "omnibus edition that collects all the works by Douglas Adams" – bear in mind that you're only considering his HHGTTG works, not _all_ the works, such as Dirk Gently.

Comment: @NigelTouch Yes of course, this question is about the *Hitchhiker* series, that sentence has to be read in its context...

Comment: @WeckarE. *Salmon* was intended as a *Dirk Gently* novel, not a *Hitchhiker* novel. If memory serves, the only *Hitchhiker*-related text in the compendium that was eventually published is *Young Zaphod Plays It Safe*.

Comment: @KyleStrand Salmon was initially intended as a Dirk Gently novel, but interviews have described how partway through Adams thought it'd fit better as a Hitchhiker book.

Comment: @WeckarE But the known bits he had planned for *Hitchhiker* were, I think, used as the basis for *And Another Thing...*, which is presumably why Thor shows up. The only actual published bit of the *Salmon* manuscript is still about Dirk Gently.